# rating system for five films in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two 3 tables as users , films and film_rate, contest.

Users will submit the film to contestid=5 and date will be insetred into the Films table using film_id and user_id from users table as per session.

Once the submissions are over, rating will be started.

Each user who has submitted(has entry in films table) films, will rate 5 film as 1,2 ,3,4, 5.

Then i want to choose the sum rating of each film and in this way i want 6 highest rated films and corresponding data from films table
Below is my  structure for film and films table.

[image: films table]

Below is my table structure for film and film_rate tables.

[image: rating table]

Everything is working fine except films selection on based of rating.
This is what i have tried , but not working like i want.

```
 $film_query_thumbs = ("select * from film f join ( select r.film_id , AVG(rating) as SumRating from film_rate r group by r.film_id ) r on r.film_id = f.film_id  where f.contestid = 5 and f.film_id='' and r.user_id IN(select user_id from film where contestid=5) order by SumRating desc limit 6" );
}
$film_query_thumbss = $conn->query($film_query_thumbs);
if($film_query_thumbss->num_rows)
{
while($thumbs=$film_query_thumbss->fetch_assoc())
{
$film_id = $thumbs['film_id'];
$thumbimage = $thumbs['thumbimage'];
$title = $thumbs['title'];
echo $title ;

}
```

but this not showing right results.

Any help please.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because the requirements are not clearly stated, nor the data.